# Constructing a measure from an integral

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory

A well known Theorem by Riesz says that every continuous linear functional on the space $C(X)$ of all complex valued continuous functions on the compact space $X$, is given as the integral against a regular Borel measure on $X$.

A purely measurable version of this would say something like:

**Theorem Template.**  Let $X$ be a set and let $\mathcal A$ be a $σ$-algebra of subsets of $X$. Denoting by $\mathcal M_+(X,\mathcal A)$ the set of all $\mathcal A$-measurable functions from $X$ to $[0,+\infty]$ (extended positive reals), suppose we are given an additive, positively homogeneous map $$I:\mathcal M_+(X,\mathcal A)\to[0,+\infty], $$ satisfying *[blank]*.  Then there exists a positive measure $\mu$ on $(X,\mathcal A)$, such that $$I(f)=\int_Xf(x)d\mu(x),$$ for all $f$ in $\mathcal M_+(X,\mathcal A)$.

> What would be a minimal set of axioms to put in place of *[blank]*?

I strongly suspect  that this must be somewhere in the literature.

> Is there a reference for a result as above?

Comment: Shouldn't $I$ be countably additive? And surely that is sufficient as well?

Comment: (For what it's worth, I believe one should also credit Markov and Kakutani for this result...)

Comment: @Ruy: Notice that the topological dual of the space of *bounded* measurable functions is the space of *finitely*-additive measures: just define $\mu (A) = I (1_A)$.

Comment: Take a look at the series of papers "Notes on Integration" by Marshall Stone.

Comment: @Alex, I should have added that by measure I mean countably additive measure.

Comment: @Nik, besides countably additive I believe the conclusion of the monotone convergence Thm should also suffice.   But my main concern is a reference.   I don't have access to Stone's paper right now, as Michael said, but it sounds like a good bet.

Comment: @Ruy: countable additivity of $I$ implies that it satisfies the MCT, this is easy.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, thanks for the reference.  It is not quite what I need, since Stone seems to be proposing a theory independent of measure theory, but it is definitely an interesting reference which I did not know about.  Plus, Stone's delicious writing style is always a pleasure to read!

Comment: I think the notion of a Daniell integral might be what you are looking for. See for example the book "Real Analysis and probability" by Dudley.